# R - Markdown - Scroll Box with Fixed Header

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, kable

Is there a way of fixing the header of a Kable table in Markdowns HTML output whilst maintaining column alignment?

```
kable(cbind(mtcars, mtcars), "html") %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  scroll_box(width = "500px", height = "200px")
```

The documentation for scroll_box does have a "fixed_thead" option, but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
scroll_box(kable_input, height = NULL, width = NULL,
  box_css = "border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px; ", extra_css = NULL,
  fixed_thead = list(enabled = F, background = "#fff"))
```

> fixed_thead A list of two named element. enabled and background.
>   Default is F and white, e.g. "list(enabled = T, background = "#fff")"

I've seen solutions using CSS, but most don't keep column alignment, is there a Kable solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran both:

```
kable(cbind(mtcars, mtcars), "html") %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  scroll_box(width = "500px", height = "200px")
```

and

```
mtcars %>% 
kable("html") %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  scroll_box(width = "500px", height = "200px")
```

Both have the same output, with column widths aligned. I don't see what the issue is, or the need to add extra css into the `scroll_box()`